# DRF Exclude from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to exclude ids from one model from foreignkey of another model. 
So i have a User model with ManyToMany going through Vote model. For now i tried many times in my ModelViewSet by .filter and .exclude and nothing working. (For sure i'm doing it bad.) From `User.vote` i'm getting ids of voted users, and i want them to be excluded from to_user, so user logged in can't vote twice the same person, and himself.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
... some code.

    vote = models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Vote,
                                           symmetrical=False,
                                           related_name='related_to+')

class Vote(models.Model):

from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
status = models.IntegerField(choices=VOTE_STATUSES)
```

and serializer:

```
class UserVoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    from_user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = UserVote
        fields = ('from_user', 'to_user', 'status')
```

Answer (score 0):

in your views add this 
**vote_from_user_ids = Vote.objects.values('from_user__id')**
now exclude vote objects from User by using
**users = User.objects.exclude(id__in = vote_from_user_ids)**

now the fromusers of vote model are excluded from User model

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'
.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserVoteSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.exclude(id__in=Vote.objects.values_list('from_user__pk', flat=True).order_by('from_user__pk')))
```

It excludes all users whose ids exist in the `from_user` field of the Vote model, i.e. the users that have already voted, and returns the users that have not yet made a vote.

Comment: With your help i'm getting same result as with Janardhan anser.AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk' .

Comment: @BartekMitorski Try writing `from_user__pk` instead of `from_user__id` in the method I wrote above. Does it give the same error?

Comment: Now that's 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'.

Comment: @BartekMitorski Could you try it now? I edited the answer a bit :)